# Google Spreadsheet: Highlight The Last Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I get my Google Spreadsheet to automatically highlight the last row of my sheet, Usually totals, in a different colour?

I am getting the following error: -

TypeError: Cannot find function setBackgroundColor in object 85. (line 19, file "Code")

and I am using the following script with no luck..

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var last_row = sheet.getLastRow()
last_row.setBackgroundColor("green");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow%28%29) returns an integer representing the number of the last populated row in the sheet, so that is just the start. You need to [get a range object using this number](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29) to be able to apply a set method.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var last_row = sheet.getLastRow(); //last populated row in sheet
var last_col = sheet.getLastColumn(); // last populated column in sheet
var range = sheet.getRange(last_row, 1, 1, last_col); //gets the range corresponding with the last populated row in the sheet
range.setBackground("green");
```

As an aside, [setBackgroundColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgroundColor%28%29) is now deprecated, use [setBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground%28String%29) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, im nearly there with creating my perfect spreadsheet!